# Прокрутка большого Canvas'а

Tags: android, java, canvas, bitmap

Есть огромное изображение (`16000х720`), я его вывожу на канвас через `drawBitmap()`. Нужно плавно его прокрутить до конца. Есть ли какие-нибудь идеи?

---

Облазил весь stackoverflow, но там ничего дельного нет

---

**UPDATE** Сделал вот такой код, но fps оставляет желать лучшего. Как оптимизировать код?
`@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

```
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    visible = Bitmap.createBitmap(track, position.x + getWidth() / 4, position.y + getHeight() / 4, getWidth(), getHeight());
    position.x++;
    canvas.drawBitmap(visible, 0, 0, pText);
    visible.recycle(); visible = null;
    invalidate();
}`
```

Comment: Ну где же вы? Мне ***очень*** нужен ваш совет!

Comment: это очень большое изображение. Я бы порезал его на кусочки (по длине) и отображал с помощью обычного listview. Его конечно придется немного поднастроить, но результат будет хороший.

Comment: Но в том то и дело, что должен использоваться только канвас или битмап. Я бы тоже с радостью в List/ScrollView полез бы)

Comment: Есть такая идея: создать битмап с картинкой такого же размера. Потом создать rect с размером экрана уст-ва и плавно прокручивать его. И на экран выводить только содержимое rect'a. Возможно ли такое? Если да, то очень прошу, помогите с кодом, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете попробовать так:
На канве через равномерные промежутки разместите битмапы поверх вашего изображения с маленькими нарисованными стрелочками вниз и вверх и настройте обработчик событий с этих битмапов на прокрутку на соответствующее расстояние.
Или нужно его прокручивать по таймеру, а не по нажатиям?

Update:  ваш код хорош, но
 1. вынесите создание битмапа из onDraw.
 2. двигайте битмап не пересозданием его в других местах, а методом объекта Canvas transform

1. Если и это не поможет и будет медленно - смотрите в сторону SurfaceView .  Буде  еще процентов на 15 быстрее. Но существенно сложнее с ней работать.

1.2.

Comment: И не по таймеру, и не по нажатию. Нужно просто автоматическое прокручивание.

Comment: Можете попробовать использовать Handler, посылая ему сообщения с нужной частотой и в обработчике двигая Canvas.
Канве нужно будет делать Invalidate().

Comment: Спасибо за совет, так и сделал - с помощью SurfaceView